# Does DatabaseReference's setValue() method have a max number of children that can be written in a single call?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I'm trying to write data into Firebase's Realtime Database from an AndroidStudio app. I have to write some Java HashMap in different children, but I noticed that when the size of the HashMap is greater than 120k, the HashMap is not stored in the Realtime Database (but no error is shown). Instead, if the size is smaller than 120k everything works fine, and each entry of the HashMap becomes an entry of the respective child in the database. Is it a size issue? How can I solve it?

This is the code I'm using:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("parent");
for(int i=0;i<myMaps.length;i++){
    myRef.child("child"+i).setValue(myMaps[i]);
}
```

EDIT: I think it's not a matter of weight. Examples:
myMaps[x] with 127k entries weighs 5.5MB ==> **Not written**
myMaps[y] with 119k entries weighs 9.7MB ==> **Written**
Also each HashMap weighs less than 11MB.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#writes):

> Size of a single write request to the database
>
> Limit: 256 MB from the REST API; 16 MB from the SDKs.
>
> Notes: The total data in each write operation should be less than 256
>   MB. Multi-path updates are subject to the same size limitation.

You are probably exceeding this limit.

I don't imagine it's the number of entries in the map that matters - it's probably the total serialized size of all the data inside it.

Comment: This is the only limit that I was already aware of: I've checked each HashMap and each of them weighs (when serialized) less than 11MB, so this shouldn't be the problem!

Comment: After reading over the limits in the documentation, if you feel that this is not working as expected, please contact Firebase support and file a bug with specific instructions that reproduce the error.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I solved it by writing the entries of the Hashmap one by one by cycling through them, but this is clearly not a solution. I reported the problem to Firebase support as you suggested!